# Reason behind (!nextProps.data.loading && this.props.data.loading)

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-apollo, apollo-client

In my react app with `react-apollo` and `react-router-redux` setup, every time I dispatch to a new route, the new query param will trigger a new GraphQL query. And I often needed callbacks after the querying is done.

I can't do that in `componentDidMount` because the component never exits, it only re-renders.

So I found this solution [here](https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo/issues/208) which uses:

```
componentWillRecieveProps(nextProps){
  if (!nextProps.data.loading && this.props.data.loading) {
    doMyCallBack();
  }
}
```

It works perfectly but I don't really understand why. As what I have noticed, `componentWillReceiveProps` gets triggered 3 times upon dispatching to a new route:

1) Upon clicking a link:

```
nextProps.data.loading: true
this.props.data.loading: false
```

2) Under what situation is both variables true?

```
nextProps.data.loading: true
this.props.data.loading: true
```

3) This is where we do our callbacks. But the data is still loading??

```
nextProps.data.loading: false
this.props.data.loading: true
```

This last one happens when the component receive new props from other actions and doesn't trigger apollo queries, which totally makes sense:

```
nextProps.data.loading: false
this.props.data.loading: false
```

I can't figure out what is going on during step 1, 2 and 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your component receives the `loading` prop from a parent component/store and `componentWillRecieveProps` fires just before that prop is applied to your component. So from what I gather:

1. `loading` is set to `true` in the store, and the store is telling your component that loading starts - it's still `false` in your component
2. it's set to `true` in both
3. `loading` is set to `false` in the store, the store is telling your component that loading is finished
4. it's set to `false` in both

1 and 3 are firing to pass the `loading` prop from the store to the component and 2 and 4 are firing due to other props being updates.
 (unrelated to loading)